# HTML Element Height Keeps Incrementing by the Second

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Purchased an off the shelf theme for my portfolio site (yes, yes...I'm too busy to design my own right now lol). Anyway I seem to be having an issue, and I have no idea when it started, where my `html` height keeps growing by 30-60px every 1-2sec.

I've tried viewing the console, however I can't find anything that's triggering this. I'm assuming that some funking Javascript is at play, and need help possibly tracking it down.

Anyone wanna lend a hand here...?

[My Site](http://bmoneruiux.com)

**UPDATE:** It seems to be caused by the smoothscroll.js file. Can any JS pro help me find the offending line of code?

```js
// SmoothScroll v1.2.1
// Licensed under the terms of the MIT license.
// People involved
//  - Balazs Galambosi (maintainer)  
//  - Patrick Brunner  (original idea)
//  - Michael Herf     (Pulse Algorithm)
//  - Justin Force     (Resurect)
// Scroll Variables (tweakable)
var framerate = 150; // [Hz]
var animtime  = 800; // [px]
var stepsize  = 80; // [px]
// Pulse (less tweakable)
// ratio of "tail" to "acceleration"
var pulseAlgorithm = true;
var pulseScale     = 8;
var pulseNormalize = 1;
// Acceleration
var acceleration   = true;
var accelDelta     = 10;  // 20
var accelMax       = 1;   // 1
// Keyboard Settings
var keyboardsupport = true;  // option
var disableKeyboard = false; // other reasons
var arrowscroll     = 50;    // [px]
// Excluded pages
var exclude = "";
var disabled = false;
// Other Variables
var frame = false;
var direction = { x: 0, y: 0 };
var initdone  = false;
var fixedback = true;
var root = document.documentElement;
var activeElement;
var key = { left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40, spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36 };
/**
 * Sets up scrolls array, determines if frames are involved.
 */
function init() {
  if (!document.body) return;
  var body = document.body;
  var html = document.documentElement;
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var scrollHeight = body.scrollHeight;
  // check compat mode for root element
  root = (document.compatMode.indexOf('CSS') >= 0) ? html : body;
  activeElement = body;
  initdone = true;
  // Checks if this script is running in a frame
  if (top != self) {
    frame = true;
  }
  /**
   * This fixes a bug where the areas left and right to
   * the content does not trigger the onmousewheel event
   * on some pages. e.g.: html, body { height: 100% }
   */
  else if (scrollHeight > windowHeight &&
           (body.offsetHeight <= windowHeight ||
            html.offsetHeight <= windowHeight)) {
    // DOMChange (throttle): fix height
    var pending = false;
    var refresh = function() {
      if (!pending && html.scrollHeight != document.height) {
        pending = true; // add a new pending action
        setTimeout(function(){
          html.style.height = document.height + 'px';
          pending = false;
        }, 500); // act rarely to stay fast
      }
    };
    html.style.height = '';
    setTimeout(refresh, 10);
    addEvent("DOMNodeInserted", refresh);
    addEvent("DOMNodeRemoved",  refresh);
    // clearfix
    if (root.offsetHeight <= windowHeight) {
      var underlay = document.createElement("div");
      underlay.style.clear = "both";
      body.appendChild(underlay);
    }
  }
  // gmail performance fix
  if (document.URL.indexOf("mail.google.com") > -1) {
    var s = document.createElement("style");
    s.innerHTML = ".iu { visibility: hidden }";
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || html).appendChild(s);
  }
  // disable fixed background
  if (!fixedback && !disabled) {
    body.style.backgroundAttachment = "scroll";
    html.style.backgroundAttachment = "scroll";
  }
}
/************************************************
 * SCROLLING
 ************************************************/
var que = [];
var pending = false;
var lastScroll = +new Date;
/**
 * Pushes scroll actions to the scrolling queue.
 */
function scrollArray(elem, left, top, delay) {
  delay || (delay = 1000);
  directionCheck(left, top);
  if (acceleration) {
    var now = +new Date;
    var elapsed = now - lastScroll;
    if (elapsed < accelDelta) {
      var factor = (1 + (30 / elapsed)) / 2;
      if (factor > 1) {
        factor = Math.min(factor, accelMax);
        left *= factor;
        top  *= factor;
      }
    }
    lastScroll = +new Date;
  }
  // push a scroll command
  que.push({
    x: left,
    y: top,
    lastX: (left < 0) ? 0.99 : -0.99,
    lastY: (top  < 0) ? 0.99 : -0.99,
    start: +new Date
  });
  // don't act if there's a pending queue
  if (pending) {
    return;
  }
  var scrollWindow = (elem === document.body);
  var step = function() {
    var now = +new Date;
    var scrollX = 0;
    var scrollY = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < que.length; i++) {
      var item = que[i];
      var elapsed  = now - item.start;
      var finished = (elapsed >= animtime);
      // scroll position: [0, 1]
      var position = (finished) ? 1 : elapsed / animtime;
      // easing [optional]
      if (pulseAlgorithm) {
        position = pulse(position);
      }
      // only need the difference
      var x = (item.x * position - item.lastX) >> 0;
      var y = (item.y * position - item.lastY) >> 0;
      // add this to the total scrolling
      scrollX += x;
      scrollY += y;
      // update last values
      item.lastX += x;
      item.lastY += y;
      // delete and step back if it's over
      if (finished) {
        que.splice(i, 1); i--;
      }
    }
    // scroll left and top
    if (scrollWindow) {
      window.scrollBy(scrollX, scrollY)
    }
    else {
      if (scrollX) elem.scrollLeft += scrollX;
      if (scrollY) elem.scrollTop  += scrollY;
    }
    // clean up if there's nothing left to do
    if (!left && !top) {
      que = [];
    }
    if (que.length) {
      requestFrame(step, elem, (delay / framerate + 1));
    } else {
      pending = false;
    }
  }
  // start a new queue of actions
  requestFrame(step, elem, 0);
  pending = true;
}
/***********************************************
 * EVENTS
 ***********************************************/
/**
 * Mouse wheel handler.
 * @param {Object} event
 */
function wheel(event) {
  if (!initdone) {
    init();
  }
  var target = event.target;
  var overflowing = overflowingAncestor(target);
  // use default if there's no overflowing
  // element or default action is prevented
  if (!overflowing || event.defaultPrevented ||
      isNodeName(activeElement, "embed") ||
        (isNodeName(target, "embed") && /\.pdf/i.test(target.src))) {
    return true;
  }
  var deltaX = event.wheelDeltaX || 0;
  var deltaY = event.wheelDeltaY || 0;
  // use wheelDelta if deltaX/Y is not available
  if (!deltaX && !deltaY) {
    deltaY = event.wheelDelta || 0;
  }
  // scale by step size
  // delta is 120 most of the time
  // synaptics seems to send 1 sometimes
  if (Math.abs(deltaX) > 1.2) {
    deltaX *= stepsize / 120;
  }
  if (Math.abs(deltaY) > 1.2) {
    deltaY *= stepsize / 120;
  }
  scrollArray(overflowing, -deltaX, -deltaY);
  event.preventDefault();
}
/**
 * Keydown event handler.
 * @param {Object} event
 */
function keydown(event) {
  var target   = event.target;
  var modifier = event.ctrlKey || event.altKey || event.metaKey ||
    (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode !== key.spacebar);
  // do nothing if user is editing text
  // or using a modifier key (except shift)
  // or in a dropdown
  if ( /input|textarea|select|embed/i.test(target.nodeName) ||
      target.isContentEditable ||
        event.defaultPrevented   ||
          modifier ) {
    return true;
  }
  // spacebar should trigger button press
  if (isNodeName(target, "button") &&
      event.keyCode === key.spacebar) {
    return true;
  }
  var shift, x = 0, y = 0;
  var elem = overflowingAncestor(activeElement);
  var clientHeight = elem.clientHeight;
  if (elem == document.body) {
    clientHeight = window.innerHeight;
  }
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case key.up:
      y = -arrowscroll;
    break;
    case key.down:
      y = arrowscroll;
    break;
    case key.spacebar: // (+ shift)
      shift = event.shiftKey ? 1 : -1;
    y = -shift * clientHeight * 0.9;
    break;
    case key.pageup:
      y = -clientHeight * 0.9;
    break;
    case key.pagedown:
      y = clientHeight * 0.9;
    break;
    case key.home:
      y = -elem.scrollTop;
    break;
    case key.end:
      var damt = elem.scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop - clientHeight;
    y = (damt > 0) ? damt+10 : 0;
    break;
    case key.left:
      x = -arrowscroll;
    break;
    case key.right:
      x = arrowscroll;
    break;
    default:
      return true; // a key we don't care about
  }
  scrollArray(elem, x, y);
  event.preventDefault();
}
/**
 * Mousedown event only for updating activeElement
 */
function mousedown(event) {
  activeElement = event.target;
}
/***********************************************
 * OVERFLOW
 ***********************************************/
var cache = {}; // cleared out every once in while
setInterval(function(){ cache = {}; }, 10 * 1000);
var uniqueID = (function() {
  var i = 0;
  return function (el) {
    return el.uniqueID || (el.uniqueID = i++);
  };
})();
function setCache(elems, overflowing) {
  for (var i = elems.length; i--;)
  cache[uniqueID(elems[i])] = overflowing;
  return overflowing;
}
function overflowingAncestor(el) {
  var elems = [];
  var rootScrollHeight = root.scrollHeight;
  do {
    var cached = cache[uniqueID(el)];
    if (cached) {
      return setCache(elems, cached);
    }
    elems.push(el);
    if (rootScrollHeight === el.scrollHeight) {
      if (!frame || root.clientHeight + 10 < rootScrollHeight) {
        return setCache(elems, document.body); // scrolling root in WebKit
      }
    } else if (el.clientHeight + 10 < el.scrollHeight) {
      overflow = getComputedStyle(el, "").getPropertyValue("overflow-y");
      if (overflow === "scroll" || overflow === "auto") {
        return setCache(elems, el);
      }
    }
  } while (el = el.parentNode);
}
/***********************************************
 * HELPERS
 ***********************************************/
function addEvent(type, fn, bubble) {
  window.addEventListener(type, fn, (bubble||false));
}
function removeEvent(type, fn, bubble) {
  window.removeEventListener(type, fn, (bubble||false));
}
function isNodeName(el, tag) {
  return (el.nodeName||"").toLowerCase() === tag.toLowerCase();
}
function directionCheck(x, y) {
  x = (x > 0) ? 1 : -1;
  y = (y > 0) ? 1 : -1;
  if (direction.x !== x || direction.y !== y) {
    direction.x = x;
    direction.y = y;
    que = [];
    lastScroll = 0;
  }
}
var requestFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback, element, delay){
    window.setTimeout(callback, delay || (1000/60));
  };
})();
/***********************************************
 * PULSE
 ***********************************************/
/**
 * Viscous fluid with a pulse for part and decay for the rest.
 * - Applies a fixed force over an interval (a damped acceleration), and
 * - Lets the exponential bleed away the velocity over a longer interval
 * - Michael Herf, http://stereopsis.com/stopping/
 */
function pulse_(x) {
  var val, start, expx;
  // test
  x = x * pulseScale;
  if (x < 1) { // acceleartion
    val = x - (1 - Math.exp(-x));
  } else {     // tail
    // the previous animation ended here:
    start = Math.exp(-1);
    // simple viscous drag
    x -= 1;
    expx = 1 - Math.exp(-x);
    val = start + (expx * (1 - start));
  }
  return val * pulseNormalize;
}
function pulse(x) {
  if (x >= 1) return 1;
  if (x <= 0) return 0;
  if (pulseNormalize == 1) {
    pulseNormalize /= pulse_(1);
  }
  return pulse_(x);
}
addEvent("mousedown", mousedown);
addEvent("mousewheel", wheel);
addEvent("load", init);
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue here. Are you sure it is not caused by some browser add-on?

Comment: I'm sure. Every time I turn on smooth roll in the theme options, this behavior starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's going on here, but the issue with smoothscroll.js still stands. Disabling it seems to have no effect on the rest of my site though so I'm moving forward.